# Stripped invalid locals information from 1 method - Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm getting this warning after `gradle build`. I think it's related to my `Proguard rules` and `Logs`. How can I "strip invalid locals information" ?

I thought wrapping my Log's to a LogUtil class:

```
public class LogUtils {
    public static void debug(final String tag, String message) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(tag, message);
        }
    }
}
```

and adding this to proguard rules

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
}
```

is a good solution but I have a lot of Log.d in my project so it'll be hard.

same issue with Timber. I think it's too late to switch

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I've fixed the issue with:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```